# Sending lot's of text using GET via AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, ckeditor

I got a simple form that sends a lot of data using ajax. I'm creating a small CMS where you can create a blog post.

The blog javascript looks like this:

```
function SaveBlog()
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML= 'Saving...';
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
            else
        {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        var TitleVar = document.getElementById('title').value;
        var editorText = CKEDITOR.instances.blogcontent.getData();
        xmlhttp.open("GET","saveblog.php?id="+<?php echo $_GET['update']; ?> + "&title=" + TitleVar + "&context=" + encodeURIComponent(editorText),true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

this is the php script behind

```
$ID = $_GET['id'];
$con = mysql_connect("", "", "");
mysql_select_db("FP", $con);
$Title = $_GET['title'];
$Context = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['context']);
mysql_query("UPDATE Blog SET BlogTitle='$Title', Entry='$Context' WHERE Identifier='$ID'");
//echo "ID: " . $_GET['id'] . " Title: " . $_GET['title'] . " Context: " . $_GET['context'];
echo '<b>Last Save: </b>' . date("F j, Y, g:i:s a");
```

everything works well, when I'm only sending like up to about 2000 characters, after, it just says "Saving..." and nothing else.

Comment: Browsers have built-in length limits on URLs. You cannot use them for arbitrary-length data transfers. As you've found out, 2000 chars is the limit in your particular browser. Use POST instead, which has no practical limits. Your SQL is also vulnerable to SQL injection attacks - you escape the context, but **NOT** the `id` or `title`. you've locked up your bank vault with a plastic sheet for a door.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a GET request, which means you're likely hitting some kind of limit in your webserver on URI length. (See: 414 Request-URI Too Large)

You should use POST instead, also your GET variable 'title' is vulnerable to SQL injection, you should escape it in the same fashion as you are with the variable 'context'

Comment: I will try that later today, and get back to you about the results, thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

For sending large payloads of data you should use POST requests - not GET requests.
Change it to a post request