# CKEditor 500 errors when posting content

Tags: ckeditor, paste

I've been using CKEditor successfully in Drupal for some time now.  Currently using v3.6.6.1.  For some reason, we recently started experiencing 500 errors after attempting to paste the content of an email (Mail.app and Outlook) into the editor, then posting the editor content.  We have a similar situation doing ajax requests with the editor and the content sample from this message.

I'm not seeing anything unusual about the text content itself when we view editor source or look at the posted encoded message in Firebug.

We have also been successfully typing and pasting text using the editor without issue so it seems to involve pasting this one particular message causing us to have the whole page blowup continue to error after an attempt to post this editor text.

Yet there is nothing we can find in the pasted content itself that might cause this or that can be removed preventatively:

```
<p>
Report is created from the selected items from all search result pages.
    Resolved - no action needed.</p>
```

So there must be something hidden that is causing to this content to trigger the errors, but how do I figure out what it is?

The encoding appears correct as well:

```
comment=%3Cp%3EReport+is+created+from+the+selected+items+from+all+
search+result+pages.+Resolved+no+action+needed.%3C%2Fp%3E
```

I'm at a loss.  Has anyone else encountered this?  Any suggestions on what to do to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

You're sending data by a GET request? Maybe your server configuration has been changed and this request is just too long.

Check this question: [Sending lot's of text using GET via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256850/sending-lots-of-text-using-get-via-ajax)

Comment: The ajax was a POST request.  We also tested the same block of text during a submit of the whole form with the same results.

Comment: Ok, then perhaps this is caused by some Drupal's internals - dunno what that can be. Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: Error logs are showing "page not found". It's like the page gets lost.